# MVC5 ActionResult model being passed as empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have read plenty of posts about this issue but I can't seem to find a solution that fits with my implementation. I'm giving MVC another attempt (I'm a webforms guy). The model being passed to my ActionResult is basically empty when it should be populated. I'm starring at the sample that works and I can find no differences. It seems to be something impossible to debug too. Any pointers will be greatfully appreciated.

View:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.SiteViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete your site";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<p>Are you sure you want to delete this site?</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"><b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</b></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">@Model.Name</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"><b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phase)</b></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">@Model.Phase</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"><b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)</b></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">@Model.Type</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Model:

```
public class SiteViewModel
{
    public SiteViewModel()
    {
        Services = new List<ServiceModel>();
    }

    public SiteViewModel(SiteModel site)
    {
        this.SiteId = site.SiteId;
        this.Name = site.Name;
        this.Type = site.Type;
        this.Phase = site.Phase;
        this.Services = site.Services;
    }

    public int SiteId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SchoolType Type { get; set; }
    public SchoolPhase Phase { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ServiceModel> Services { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(SiteViewModel model)
    {
        var site = siteRepository.GetById(model.SiteId);
        if (site == null) { throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Site with Id [{0}] does not exist", model.SiteId)); }

        try
        {
            siteRepository.SoftDeleteAndSubmit(site);

            base.SetSuccessMessage("The site has been (soft) deleted.");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            base.SetErrorMessage("Whoops! Couldn't delete the site. The error was [{0}]", ex.Message);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Your form above does not contain any <input> elements so it will not submit any data to your Delete action.

Comment: Hi Jasen. Neither does the sample project I am following (see: http://www.christiaanverwijs.nl/post/2013/12/05/Entity-Framework-MVC-Repositories-Code-First-Migrations-Putting-it-together.aspx). I therefore doubt this to be the issue.

Comment: The `Html.TextBoxFor()` helper will generate <input> elements. That blog post does not show any view code but his git repository shows that he uses these helper methods.

Comment: Hi Jasen, there is no helper is his example. The specific page in his example that works is https://bitbucket.org/cverwijs/examples.mvcwithef/src/c22c83e5f6f9130224437f14027ed7517f6bbe2f/WebSite/Views/Application/Delete.cshtml?at=master

Comment: I've run that code and I'm surprised it works that way -- not saying he's wrong. If you debug by putting stop right after entering the POST delete you will see that none of the parameters for the model are populated except the id. If you also watch a network monitor while you do this you will see that there are no form items posted except for the validation token. You will also see that the URL is `/Application/Delete/1` so the id is being bound as the model. In short, if you want a fully-populated model on post use <input> elements.

Comment: Jasen, the strange thing is, my code isn't even populating the Id. If it at least did that, the code would work.

Comment: Rename `SiteId` to `Id` to match the routing rules. But I wouldn't rely on that and would just pass an `int id` instead of the model.

Comment: Thanks Jansen. That did it. I feel such a derp but am still learning MVC. Post that as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a fully-populated model you'll need to use form elements or the form helper functions to post your data.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" value="@Model.Name" />
    // or
    Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    ...
}
```

The example you linked relies on a URL routing rule to match a model's parameter. So you need to rename `SiteId` to `Id` or add/modify a routing rule.

If you only need the id then I would just pass that parameter as it will make your intent more obvious and is less prone to breaking.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var site = siteRepository.GetById(id);
    ...
}
```